# different result in print command because of in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python and am still learning. I wanted to know what is the difference between these two commands and why do they output different results.

Without white space

```
 hello = []
 for letter in 'word':
 hello.append(letter)
print(hello)
```

Output

```
['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```

---

With White space

```
hello = []
for letter in 'word':
hello.append(letter)
print(hello)
```

output

```
['w']
['w', 'o']
['w', 'o', 'r'] 
['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```

Comment: Your indentation is key to this problem, and it's incorrect in your question. Presumably you have `print` indented to be inside the `for` loop in your actual code for the second example.

Comment: I have a hunch that the indentation in the code you posted is not the same as the indentation in the code you are running. If something is indented under a `for` loop, it is part of the body, and will be executed every time through the loop. The `print` expression is behaving the same way in both cases; it's all about where you put it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't run due to indentation errors.  If it's where you indented your `print`, then any tutorial on Python loops should explain the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python interprets the code based on tabbed whitespace (really it is 4 spaces).

In the first example, you append all the letters of the word into a list, and then you print the contents of the list. Here, you are only printing the contents of the list *after* the loop is executed.

```
lst = []
for letter in 'word':
    lst.append(letter)
print(lst)
```

In the second example, you append the letters of the word into a list, but you also print the contents of the list *within* the loop. So every time a letter is added, you print the contents of what's inside that list. Note: the difference here is that the print statement is *within* the loop, and not outside of it.

```
lst = []
for letter in 'word':
    lst.append(letter)
    print(lst)
```

Comment: Your examples are correct but "Python interprets the code based on tabbed whitespace." probably isn't the best advice. The suggested indentation in PEP8 is 4 spaces.... good IDEs just translate tabs to 4 spaces.

Comment: @zachary thanks a lot. It really helps my understanding of foundation in python.